# How do I switch between 2 image using UISegmentcontrol?

Tags: xcode4.3, uisegmentedcontrol

I've tried writing this code but I don't think it's correct cause there is an error with the viewDidLoad.

I'm trying to switch between 2 images in the same UIImageView using UISegmentcontol using Storyboard. All the examples online are for switching labels and not using Xcode storyboard.

### h.file

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface ViewController : UIViewController

    {

        IBOutlet UIImageView *myImage;
        IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segControl;
     }

    @property(nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UIImageView *myImage;

    @property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segControl;

    - (IBAction)switchButton:(id)sender;

    @end
```

### m.file

```
    #import "ViewController.h"

    @interface ViewController ()


    @end

    @implementation ViewController

    @synthesize myImage;
    @synthesize segControl;


    - (IBAction)switchButton:(id)sender
    {
      if (segControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
    {
      [myImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.jpg"]];

     }

    else

     if (segControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
    {
      [myImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.jpg"]];

    }



    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
       [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        UIImage *myImage = [myImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.jpg"]];

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fill the segments of the segmented control with images, you don't need code.  Just use the storyboard.